# Mix 2 mp3 files with FFmpeg for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am developing something similar to a karaoke app. I have a sound file(beat) and a recorded file(voice) from android mediarecorder. I am trying to mix the two files to become one file that plays the same time. I have set up ffmpeg provided by writingminds and everything is working fine. I am not familiar with ffmpeg commands so searched for and got few commands that can achieve the task for me. This is the code i got:

```
  String files = "-i " + currentFile + " -i " + someFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String output = mFileName + "/recorded/test.mp3";
            String cmd = "ffmpeg "+files+
                    " -filter_complex \"aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];[0:a][ac1]amix[aout]\" -map [aout] -c:a libmp3lame " + output;
```

But it not working. this is the error i got:

```
04-01 12:09:26.598 21300-21300/com.shixels.thankgodrichard.mixer I/fpeg: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                           built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                           configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                           libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                           libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                           libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                           libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                           libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                           libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                           libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                           libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                         Output #0, mp3, to 'ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/MyStudio/temps/1491044929409.mp3 -i /storage/emulated/0/temp.mp3 -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];[0:a][ac1]amix[aout]" -map [aout] -c:a libmp3lame /storage/emulated/0/recorded/test.mp3':
                                                                         Output file #0 does not contain any stream
04-01 12:09:26.599 21300-21300/com.shixels.thankgodrichard.mixer I/fpeg: finished
```

I read some answers here saying it depends on the version of the ffmpeg your using. I am using the latest ffmpeg for android by writingminds.

Comment: It's treating the entire cmd string as output name.  Maybe the ffmpeg at the beginning needs to be avoided.

Comment: Tried it but it did not work @Mulvya

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for android, but in unix, you could use this command, maybe it helps you:

`ffmpeg -filter_complex "amovie=file1.mp3 [a0]; amovie=file2.mp3 [a1]; [a0][a1] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest [aout]" -map [aout] -acodec mp3 file_merged.mp3`

Comment: @Diego This command does not do any concatenation like the one in the question, and in this case you can use `-i input` instead of `amovie`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard as he said: "mix the two files to become one file that plays the same time". This is not a concatenation, is a merge... And yes, you can use -i for inputs and then [0:a] and [1:a] to use them in filter complex, both ways are valid

Comment: Your command omits the concatenation that was present in the original, and using `amovie` instead of `-i` is just weird.